# Creating custom map projection based on mathematical formula

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations

For example, the formula for the Mercator projection is as follows:

[image]

Suppose I want to create a map using my OWN formula.

What are the tools I can use to achieve this?

I seek a solution using Python, such as the `GeoPandas` library or `cartopy`, but I do not mind if I need to use something else.

Is it possible to create it with a `proj4` string? (because if so then I can add that to GeoPandas).

Comment: proj4 wouldn't know what to do with your string until it was modified to do so. So, first you'd have to modify proj4 (and all the open-source libraries) to support your new projection, and then convince a standards body to support extending the list of "standard" projections to include your implementation, along with sufficient detail that commercial developers would implement it too.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing this for a small paper (not a thesis or anything), so I don't need to provide any information for other people to use it, I just want to be able to **display** a map using the new projection. What could I do?

Comment: You'd still need to modify the source and build a custom library, possibly adding hooks to the tool which would invoke it. Otherwise you have to write the projection code *and* a reader and writer for the data format.  Either way, these sort of details belong in the question body.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details in the question body, I really don't know how I would even start. Should I be using something other than proj? I just want to create a map with a custom mathematically defined formula, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not how it works.  In order to use existing mapping code, you need data in a supported format. In order to write data from one format to another with existing tools in a custom projection, you'd need to implement that projection.  Otherwise you can write a translator and not mark the projection of the resulting data. This is research you need to do. Then, if you have difficulty, a question that focuses on those details would be on-topic here.

Comment: I found this https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/custom_projection.html tool that allows me to create a custom map projection using python matplotlib, but I wasn’t able to figure out how to get a visual representation of the map. This method wouldn’t work?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to ask your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this is more of a mathematics problem than GIS, because most GIS software have a set number of built-in projections that you can't edit or add to. You can create a new "coordinate system", but it has to be based on one of the built-in projections.

If you did create a new projection you could simply display it as a grid (graph) using math software and then you could probably use a GIS to warp a map to fit it. That would be one way.

But having said that, there is a piece of software I know of that might help. Check out http://www.flexprojector.com/index.html - it's been a while since I used it, but it does let you manually define a projection and even shows a world map outline as the background.

[image]

But as others have said, you are unlikely to be able to add this to any particular GIS without adding it to an official library of coordinate systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I haven't been able to figure out how to simply insert a mathematical formula into FlexProjector? (e.g. the mercator projection formula). 

As you said, "simply display it as a grid (graph) using math software and then use a GIS to warp a map to fit it." is what I've been trying to do, but I haven't been able to figure out how to warp the map to fit it. I asked that question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536774/add-stock-image-to-custom-projection-matplotlib

Comment: Yes, it's been a while since I used that software and I can't install it now because I don't have JRE on my machine. Perhaps you could contact the developers? I believe it's a university project so I expect they'd be open to questions and interest in it.

Comment: @MarkIreland FME SDK allows this see answer below.

Comment: @JimT - you could certainly create a plugin that processes a formula. But I don't think you can add a specific projection to FME. You can create any number of coordinate systems, but only using a projection that is already defined. At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: Yes and no - It's more subtle than that - correct about not adding a whole new projection type to the base library - however one _can_ create a new reprojector transformer that inherits the FME reprojection capabilities (thus applying to all data types), but featuring a new formula.

Answer (score 0):

The FME [SDK](https://community.safe.com/s/article/developing-a-new-transformer-using-the-fme-plug-in) allows the creation of plugins to create new transformers.

One of the out-of-the-box SDK examples is a reprojector plugin which Inherits from the FME API class *IFMEReprojectEngine*.  This creates a new reprojection engine DLL that FME can use just like the inbuilt engine.

Using this example as the base, you can develop the code & DLL for your new projection.  This plugin can then be used within FME to convert data into the new coordinate system.

However, when mapping the data in another GIS platform - you may have to state all data is in a [local grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387415/specifying-a-non-earth-unknown-crs).

As an example - the FME SDK is used to create the [SnakeGrid Projector](http://snakegrid.org/software/snakegrid-projector) plugin.

[Note: see this [GIS SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226986/creating-new-projected-coordinate-system-for-the-world-in-arcmap) for creating a whole new projection type in ArcGIS.]